# NVD3 chart bars don't properly stack for inconsistently ordered keys for data series

Tags: nvd3.js

NDV3 chart bars don't stack properly when the JSON object keys (for series) are not consistently ordered. `unsorted_keys_data` has *"one": "BB", "CC", "AA"* & *"two": "CC", "AA", "BB"* instead of  *"AA", "BB", "CC"* in the same order for both objects.

See [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mioritics/z4aZ4/566/).

Would there be any workaround this?

[image: improperly stacked bars]

[image: properly stacked bars]

```
var sorted_keys_data = [
    {
    "key": "one",
    "values": [
        {"x": "AA", "y": 0.2},
        {"x": "BB", "y": 0.8},
        {"x": "CC", "y": 0.3}
        ]
    },
    {
    "key": "two",
    "values": [
        {"x": "AA", "y": 0.5},
        {"x": "BB", "y": 0.4},
        {"x": "CC", "y": 0.6}
        ]
    }
]


var unsorted_keys_data = [
    {
    "key": "one",
    "values": [
        {"x": "BB", "y": 0.8},
        {"x": "CC", "y": 0.3},
        {"x": "AA", "y": 0.2}
        ]
    },

{
    "key": "two",
    "values": [
        {"x": "CC", "y": 0.6},
        {"x": "AA", "y": 0.5},
        {"x": "BB", "y": 0.4}
        ]
    }
]
```